# Как посмотреть формируемый запрос?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть метод, к БД `CIBlockElement::GetList(....` он возвращает `CIBlockResult`, который, как я понимаю, можно использовать как для получения выборки, так и для просмотра SQL запроса, который выполнялся. Как можно посмотреть этот запрос?

Долго искал в поисковике - но результата не дало

Answer (score 1):

```
$element = new CIBlockElement;
    $element->strField = "ID";
    $res = $element->GetList(array(), $arElementFilter, false, false, array("ID"));
echo $res;
```

Comment: Находил такой вариант в интернете, но они не показывает запрос. только данный коннекта БД

Comment: Наверное поменяли Api. В админке тогда смотреть запросы. Или в самом мониторе SQL